# How can bennies be spent to gain combat edges?

Tags: savage-worlds

I know I've read of a way to spend bennies to use an edge on the fly.  For example, a player could spend a benny to buy first strike before an opponent moves and then attack them (per first strike's rules).  After that round, the edge is lost unless more bennies are spent.

I believe the edge that is purchased has to be a combat edge.  I can't remember where I read about this ability, or if it's an edge itself or an alternate rule.  I skimmed through the Deluxe edition but didn't see it immediately.

Has anyone heard of this rule before, and know if it can be found in any books?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "High Adventure" setting rule in Savage Worlds Deluxe provides the option of spending a benny to gain a Combat Edge for one round, and War of the Dead offers a similar setting rule. I'm not aware of any *official* Edges that offer the same option, but the Dynamic Warrior Edge in my [Savage War of the Burning Sky](http://www.godwars2.org/SavageWorlds/SWotBS_PG.pdf) conversion gives the ability.

Comment: Aha!  This is exactly what I was trying to find.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is also the Battlelords Blessing in Sundered Skies Setting.

It is a Power that grants the recipient any Combat Edge. BUT the caster itself must meet the requirements.

Comment: Battlelord's Blessing is almost identical to Warrior's Gift in the core rules.